# .html() doesn't change content if placed before confirm() and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to change the content of an element using .html() to indicate that a process has started.

But the problem is that it won't work no matter what I do. I might be missing something here that prevents the script from working.

Code:

```
if(counter < 1 && flag == true){
                                alert("test");
                                $("#updownform").html("Please Wait...");
//                                if(confirm("Are you sure you want to proceed?")){
//                                    counter++;
//                                    $.ajax({
//                                        method: "POST",
//                                        url: "index.php?module=Accounts&action=processUpdowngrade",
//                                        data: {form_data: $(this).serialize()},
//                                        success: function (datas) {
//                                            counter = 10000;
//                                            location.reload();
//                                        }
//                                    });
//                                }else{
//                                    $("#updownform").html("Save changes");
//                                }
                            }
```

In this example where everything is commented out except for the alert and .html(). The .html() works but if I uncomment everything it will only work when AJAX is finished with the request even after the confirm condition was triggered. Which I found weird since I already placed it before the confirm condition. So ideally it would have executed before the confirm condition.

I also tried using beforeSend but it still didn't work. I also tried setting it to asynch:false/true together with beforeSend to no avail.

Comment: Comment for the downvote? Also, My question is pretty clear. I even stated it in the explanation. Even the title is self-explanatory.

Comment: So you want the confirm to happen before or after the ajax request?

Comment: @JeanPaul98 the confirm will always happen before the ajax request since the ajax is inside the confirm. My problem here is the .html which I want to execute before the AJAX

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying the code below to see if it helps.

```
<script>
if (counter < 1 && flag == true) {
    alert("test");
    document.getElementById("updownform").value = "Please Wait...";
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to proceed?")) {
        counter++;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php?module=Accounts&action=processUpdowngrade",
            data: $("#enter_your_form_id").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function(data) {
                counter = 10000;
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    } else {
        document.getElementById("updownform").value = "Save changes";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer but what did you change?

Comment: You had `method: "POST" and your `success: function(data) {` was `success: function(datas) {` but `datas` was nowhere to be found in your code? Did it work?